# Invisible or corrupted font Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fonts

I turned on my PC today and had a little surprise, the font used by Windows is not rendering or has been corrupted and now Windows Explorer look like that:

[image: that]

I wanted to try to reinstall the font by going in

> C:\Windows\Fonts\

but the interface is not rendered properly and I can't click on "Install"

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Use a restoration point from before the problem appeared.  Additionally you can use the appropriate DISM command to repair your system corruption.

Comment: I sometimes have the same thing in one of the programs I use. Closing and reopening that program usually fixes it. Have you rebooted?

Comment: @LPChip I rebooted, tried to install the last updates with Windows Update. Also, the problems occurs everywhere in Windows and in many programs, for example the URL in the Chrome is not displayed

Comment: Ok, so you don't have the problem I have. Ramhoud's suggestion is the best next thing to do then.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried to execute DISM commands but no issue has been detected so I just restored using a restoration point and it worked, so thank you for your answer and your rapidity.